# NSDictionary may not respond to setObject:forKey on a NSMutableDictionary object

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdictionary

I am new to Xcode and I am trying out this small program.

```
//  BookStoreMine.h
//  BookStore

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Book.h"

@interface BookStoreMine : NSObject {
NSDictionary* mybookStore;

}
@property (retain) NSDictionary* myBookStore;

-(id)init;
-(void)printInventory;
-(BOOL)addBook:(Book *)newBook;
-(BOOL)removeBookWithTitle:(NSString *)whichTitle;
-(void)dealloc;

@end

//  BookStoreMine.m
//  BookStore
#import "BookStoreMine.h"


@implementation BookStoreMine
@synthesize myBookStore;

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
    myBookStore = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

-(BOOL)addBook:(Book *)newBook {
**[myBookStore setObject:newBook forKey:newBook.title];**
return YES;
}    

-(BOOL) removeBookWithTitle:(NSString *)whichTitle{
if ([myBookStore objectForKey:whichTitle] != nil) {
    **[myBookStore removeObjectForKey:whichTitle];**
    return YES;
}
return NO;
}

-(void)printInventory{
Book *book;
for (NSString* key in myBookStore) {
    book = [myBookStore objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@" Title: %@",book.title);
    NSLog(@" Author: %@",book.author);
    NSLog(@" Description: %@",book.description);
    NSLog(@"ID is:%@",book.ID);
}
}

-(void)dealloc{
self.myBookStore = nil;
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I get warnings on the lines where I use setObject method on myBookStore and also when I use the removeObject method on the myBookStore object. The warning is "NSDictionary may not respond to setObject:forKey or removeObject:forKey. Why am I getting a warning related to NSDictionary when the object I am using is a NSMutableDictionary? How do I get rid of the warning? (PS: The program compiles and runs without any problem)

Answer (score 6):

At **runtime** you are setting the `myBookStore` object to be an instance of `NSMutableDictionary`.

At **compile time**, it's still declared as an `NSDictionary`, which doesn't respond to the messages for set or remove.

If you declare the variable as an `NSMutableDictionary`, the warnings will go away.

Answer (score 5):

Change these two lines:

```
NSDictionary* mybookStore;

@property (retain) NSDictionary* myBookStore;
```

to look like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* mybookStore;

@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary* myBookStore;
```

Xcode is looking at the declarations of ivars when determining what methods they implement, and if you should always declare ivars as what they are going to be be.

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense! I am wondering why the compiler allowed me to define the variable and its property as NSDictionary and let me define it at runtime as NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: There are times when you might need to declare a variable as one class and then have it be a subclass when actually used. For example if you have a view controller that could be one of several specific subclasses. FOr those times you can just cast the variable.

Answer (score 4):

You've declared `mybookStore` as an NSDictionary. The compiler therefore believes it to be an `NSDictionary`. The fact that an NSMutableDictionary is assigned to it at runtime doesn't alter that.

Probably you want to change the declaration within your `@interface` to an `NSMutableDictionary` (though it still makes sense to return it as immutable in your `@property`, as you don't want external actors to think they have the right to modify it).

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that your intention is to give the user of your class an `immutable` `NSDictionary` so they cannot modify the ivar you are using internally. Judging by the fact you have this method declared

```
-(void)printInventory;
```

I would guess that really the user of your class does not need to see the `NSDictionary` ivar at all. If this is the case then what I normally do is not declare the ivar that I will use internally in the header file at all. This has the effect of making the user of my class use the getters/setters provided and I can change the internal data structure anytime I want. To achieve this you will need to use a class extension to add the additional ivar.

This will make your class look like this - notice how much cleaner your header file (public API) looks:

```
//  BookStoreMine.h
//  BookStore

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Book.h"

@interface BookStoreMine : NSObject

- (void)printInventory;
- (BOOL)addBook:(Book *)newBook;
- (BOOL)removeBookWithTitle:(NSString *)whichTitle;

@end

//  BookStoreMine.m
//  BookStore
#import "BookStoreMine.h"

@interface BookStoreMine ()

@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary* myBookStore;

@end

@implementation BookStoreMine

@synthesize myBookStore;

- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
      myBookStore = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)addBook:(Book *)newBook 
{
  [self.myBookStore setObject:newBook forKey:newBook.title];
  return YES;
}    

- (BOOL)removeBookWithTitle:(NSString *)whichTitle 
{
  if ([myBookStore objectForKey:whichTitle] != nil) {
    [self.myBookStore removeObjectForKey:whichTitle];
    return YES;
  }
  return NO;
}

- (void)printInventory
{
  Book *book;
  for (NSString* key in self.myBookStore) {
    book = [myBookStore objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@" Title: %@",book.title);
    NSLog(@" Author: %@",book.author);
    NSLog(@" Description: %@",book.description);
    NSLog(@"ID is:%@",book.ID);
  }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  [myBookStore release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```